# Are damage over time effects affected by spell vamp?

Tags: league-of-legends

There are several spells that apply damage over time effects to your opponents, such as Cassiopeia's poisons, Teemo's `Toxic Shot` and his bombs, and so on.  Do these effects activate your spell vamp, since they are begun and technically the effect of an ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes all damage over time effects trigger spell vamp immediately, for the entire duration and percentage of damage dealt:

> Damage over time abilities (DoT) apply full spell vamp.

Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Spell_vamp

> For single-target DoT spells, spell vamp will be applied to the total amount of damage dealt by all ticks.

Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Damage_over_time

*The only skills that don't benefit fully from spell vamp are **area of effect (AoE)**, which apply only 1/3 of the spell vamp effect.*